# Troubles overriding java method in jruby

Tags: java, ruby, jruby

I'm having some troubles overriding a java method from a jruby class. Since JRuby exposes java methods with both camel and snake case syntaxes, i've tried both approaches to override the same method, but i'm having strange results:

JAVA

```
package tabaqui;

class MyJavaClass {
  public void myMethod() {
    System.out.println("Java method");
  }

  public void invokeMyMethod() {
    myMethod();
  }
}
```

RUBY

```
class MyRubyClass1 < Java::tabaqui.MyJavaClass
  def my_method
    puts "Ruby method from MyRubyClass1\n";
  end
end

class MyRubyClass2 < Java::tabaqui.MyJavaClass
  def myMethod
    puts "Ruby method from MyRubyClass2\n";
  end
end

a = MyRubyClass1.new
a.my_method          #output: "Ruby method from MyRubyClass1"
a.invoke_my_method   #output: "Java method"

b = MyRubyClass2.new
b.my_method          #output: "Java method"
b.invoke_my_method   #output: "Ruby method from MyRubyClass2"
```

The only solution i've found to obtain the expected result (ruby methods invoked in every case) is giving the overridden method an alias after defining it in ruby:

```
alias_method :myMethod, :my_method
```

Am i doing something wrong?

Comment: I think JRuby automatically converts method names from java's camelCase to ruby's snake_case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

while confusing at first sight, this is "expected" once you understand alias ...

`MyJavaClass#myMethod` will have a `my_method` alias setup by the JRuby runtime.

in `MyRubyClass1` you redefined `my_method` (alias) thus seeing the expected output.
however you did not override `myMethod` -> the convention does not work backwards.

while in `MyRubyClass2` you redefined `myMethod` so it ends up doing virtual Java dispatch from `invokeMyMethod()`, es expected.

while this might seem confusing its how it is, the Java alias conventions are really there for "bare" consumers. while if you're extending a Java class you should stick to proper Java names. there's room for improvement here to re-define Java aliases once a proxy class is generated, although it might be a breaking change.